# How to link to databases to get a result

Tags: python, mysql

I have this code:

```
get_amount_sum = []
query = "SELECT amount FROM customers_payments7 WHERE date_ <= %s"
mycursor.execute(query,(to_date,))
for cursor in mycursor:
    get_amount_sum.append(cursor[0])
    sum_amount_eisprakseis = sum(get_amount_sum)


query = f"SELECT customer_surname, SUM(amount) FROM set_payment7 GROUP BY customer_surname"
mycursor.execute(query)
for row in mycursor:
    file.write("\t".join(map(str, row)))
    file.write("\n")
```

What it does: it is getting the sum of the amount of what a customer has paid me and then it is getting the sum of the amount of what a customer needs to pay me. The result from the code is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMOyd.png

What I want to do is to get the difference between the amount the customer has already paid me and the amount of what the customer needs to pay me and put it in the AMOUNT section in the picture. Currently, it is displaying only the amount that the customer needs to pay me but I want somehow to get the difference between these 2. For example, if customer abc has paid me 100 euros and he has to pay me 200 euros I want to get 200-100 = 100.

Is there any solution?

Comment: How do we know which amounts have been paid and which have not?

Comment: We don't, we declare the amount the customer has to pay and then the amount he has already paid. So in the amount section in the text file, it has to write the amount the customer has to pay minus the amount the customer has already paid. My problem is that these 2 amounts are from different tables in my database.

Comment: Then you need to share the structure (ideally, result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`)  of these tables, so we can see how they should be joined.